# How to analytically solve this ODEs?

Tags: differential-equations, statistical-physics

I don't think these ODEs have been explicitly solved before, and I'm wondering if anyone can point me to some papers which might help me start.

Here $n$ is an integer and $S_A,S_B$ can be seen as given input.

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}X_A &= -X_A - X_Aw_{AB}X^n_B+S_A,\\
\frac{d}{dt}X_B &= -X_B - X_Bw_{BA}X^n_A+S_B.
\end{align*}

Comment: Some pointers concerning writing mathematics on Stack Exchange sites: [How does one type mathematical formulas on this site?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3763)

Comment: there is no closed-form solution, I would just solve them numerically.

Comment: Are $S_A, S_B$ functions or constants and what is $w_{AB}$?

Comment: What does it mean "analytically"?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko - I think in this context it's the antonym of "numerically" (but you won't find it listed as such in the Thesaurus).

Comment: @Michael Engelhart: I do not understand what is an antonym of "numerically", so give me some examples. Can the equation $y'=y$ be solved "analytically"? There is a theorem (of Cauchy) saying that for many differential equations all solutions are analytic (this includes the equation in the question.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko - well, an antonym of "numerically" means "non-numerically", i.e., "produced without using computation in terms of specific numerals" (maybe one can say it better). I.e., "analytically" here has nothing to do with the concept of analytic functions. The example $y'=y$ is confusing, because we can solve it analytically in both senses, so this won't help to distinguish the two usages. Maybe $y'''''+y''''+y'''+y''+y'+y=0$ is an example that distinguishes.

Comment: I still don't quite understand how you propose to solve y'=y non-numerically. The solutions are power series. You can solve more or less any ODE in terms of power series.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko - well, the statement $y=e^x$ would usually be accepted as a "non-numerical", i.e., "analytical" form of solution. Of course, to evaluate it at $x=1/2$ would require some numerical computation. Certainly, these are all somewhat subjective, "I know it when I see it" terms. Similar to discussions about what constitutes a "known" function (how elementary does it have to be ...)

Comment: @MichaelEngelhart: you understood my point: the question is not well defined.

Answer (score 2):

(I doubt this system in general is solvable) but a starting point is to consider $S_A = S_B = 0$ and $W_{AB}, W_{BA}$ are constant

$$ \frac{dX_A}{dt} = -X_A(1+W_{AB}X_B^n)  \\ \frac{dX_B}{dt} = -X_B(1+W_{BA}X_A^n)  $$

so it follows that

$$ \frac{dX_A}{dX_B} = \frac{X_A}{1+W_{BA}X_A^n } \frac{1+W_{AB}X_B^n}{X_B} $$

Now you have a solution possible. Simply solve the differential equation

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{1+W_{BA}y^n} $$

Then $$y\left( \int \frac{1+W_{AB}X_B^n}{X_B}  dX_B\right) $$ solves your original equation via chain rule.

We can stretch this further by consider non constant $W$ (as long as $W_{BA}$ depends on $X_A$ and $W_{AB}$ depends on $X_B$ this is really fine). We can also let $S_A, S_B$ be finite degree polynomials say of maximum degree $k$, since we can just differentiate  the expressions $k$ times to send them to 0 and that general abstract trick above is still workable as you'll now have separable equations.